# Divi Builder render html code on post type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a website and I meet an issue with Divi / CPT UI.
I create a post type name "tente". In order to build the page with Divi builder, I add in function.php this code :

```
function my_et_builder_post_types( $post_types ){
    $post_types[] = 'tentes';
    return $post_types;
}
add_filter('et_builder_post_types', 'my_et_builder_post_types');
```

This is working, because I can use Divi builder in post type.

But, when I use tab element, the builder render HTML code on my website.

See what I've done :
[image]

And what it give to me on website :
[image]

I look at the Divi doc. I don't found something interesting about it.
Some of you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are on the latest version of Divi if not you need to update. Divi now allows for custom post types to get access to the builder. If you updated then do the following:

1. Remove the code you added above
2. In my case, I use CPT UI and have a post type named Doctors as shown below [image: Doctors custom post type]
3. Just go to Divi --> Theme options --> Builder --> Post Type Integration and make sure you Custom post type shows as Enabled as shown below

[image: Divi Post Type Integration]
Your code might work but it's better to use the built-in way now that it exists.

Now, for the HTML problem.

1. Make sure you are in text mode **NOT** visual mode as shown below

[image: Stay in text mode]

2. Add the required shortcode to create 3 tabs

   [et_pb_tabs admin_label="Tabs" use_border_color="off" border_color="#ffffff" border_style="solid"] [et_pb_tab title="Description" tab_font_select="default" tab_line_height="2em" tab_line_height_tablet="2em" tab_line_height_phone="2em" body_font_select="default" body_line_height="2em" body_line_height_tablet="2em" body_line_height_phone="2em"]
   This is title1
   [/et_pb_tab][et_pb_tab title="Managment" tab_font_select="default" tab_line_height="2em" tab_line_height_tablet="2em" tab_line_height_phone="2em" body_font_select="default" body_line_height="2em" body_line_height_tablet="2em" body_line_height_phone="2em"]
   This is title2.

[/et_pb_tab][et_pb_tab title="Photos" tab_font_select="default" tab_line_height="2em" tab_line_height_tablet="2em" tab_line_height_phone="2em" body_font_select="default" body_line_height="2em" body_line_height_tablet="2em" body_line_height_phone="2em"]
This is title3.
[/et_pb_tab] [/et_pb_tabs]

This gives the following result

[image: Result]

Now look at the above code while you are still in **TEXT MODE** and add your HTML where it says This is title1, This is title2 and This is title3 to populate the tabs with what you need. Hope this helps